# Tool for analyzing memory leaks in a COM object

Tags: c++, windows, com

If there is a tool for analyzing memory leaks in a c++ COM Object, please provide a link here

If no such tool exist, what would be the best way to handle memory leaks ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

There's a tool 'valgrind'. It's one of the best memory leak checkers, but I'm not sure if it exists for windows... Give it a try

Comment: Valgrind dosen't have a release for Windows, and no support for cygwin either.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Deleaker, it tracks resource leaks in addition to memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LeakDiag (and LDParser, LDGrapher), good for unmanaged code, including COM.

Answer (score 0):

AQtime can help to catch memory leaks. But it's a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing the COM object or simply using it? Do you have the source?

If you don't have the source then you're pretty much on your own.

If you do then any 'normal' memory leak checker will work. I use Bounds Checker which is part of the MicroFocus DevPartner Studio product (see here http://www.microfocus.com/products/micro-focus-developer/devpartner/visual-c.aspx). It's commercial but there's a trial available that might help you...